# Make API update to Subscribers from Sales cloud To Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, sfmc-business-unit, unsubscribe

I have a custom object in Salesforce which stores the value of the Subscriber key in Marketing Cloud.

I want to make an API call to update the subscriber Status to "UnSubscribed" in Marketing cloud but in a specific business unit (As I have four Business Units) , also we are using Version 2.0 of Marketing cloud.

How can we make the API call to Unsubscribe from Specific Business Unit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize this [Unsubscribe and Log an Unsub Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm). In order to unsubscribe from your child BU, you need to have the following settings in the setup section.

> Subscribers will be unsubscribed from this business unit only
> Read more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_unsubscribe_settings.htm&type=5)

Comment: I tried thies event as well but it did not work out to me. I'm recieving the status as 200 OK, but it is not updating the Subscriber Status in Marketing cloud.